# Error while installing / using google-api-python-client

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

Each time I am installing or using the python google api (google-api-python-client), I have the following error:

```
Error processing line 2 of /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapis_common_protos-1.1.0-nspkg.pth:


  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 158, in addpackage

      exec line

    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  KeyError: 'google'

Remainder of file ignored
```

It doesn't seem to affect the installation or the usage but I would like to get rid of this error (and I don't know if it might have some effect one day).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something in the install path didn't get installed properly. Can you try to remove as much of what wasn't fully installed and try again using `pip`? I.e., `pip install -U google-api-python-client` (or `pip3` for Python 3 users). Please update your post with any errors you get from running that.